# xhr upload returns status 0 in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, blob

The code below is working in IE and Chrome but not in any version of firefox that I try. In firefox I get a status of 0 in the xhr.onload function instead of a status of 200.
Also in firefox for a response I am getting Blob { size: 9728, type: "application/xml" } but in chrome I am getting Blob {type: "text/plain", size: 9728, slice: function}

```
       function fileUpload(idx){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', upload_q[q_index_get(idx)], true);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            var uid = Math.random().toString(34).substr(2);
            xhr.onload = function(e) {
                console.log('---- this.status ----');
                console.log(this.status);
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    var myBlob = this.response; 
                    // myBlob is now the blob that the object URL pointed to.
                    console.log(myBlob);
                    var oMyForm = new FormData();
                    oMyForm.append("uid", uid );
                    oMyForm.append("fname", upload_fname_q[q_index_get(idx)]);
                    oMyForm.append("fsize", myBlob.size)
                    oMyForm.append("q_key", idx)
                    oMyForm.append("myFile", myBlob);
                    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    oReq.open("POST", "/client/upload");
                    oReq.send(oMyForm);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
            return uid;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped checking if status == 200 and the upload works. The strange thing is that I created that code based on what I read on MDN.